# Want to get in shape

Tags: diet, workout-routines, body-fat, getting-in-shape

Guys I want to get in shape. I want to know how can I reduce belly fat. I am of 5ft 3 inches. Having a weight of 70 kg. With a lot of fat on my belly. I am 22 years old. I want to know what workout should I do in gym. I am a beginner. And also what type of diet plan should I follow as a vegan.

Comment: Before any dispute: The accepted answer in that question applies to herbivores and carnivores alike.

Answer (score 3):

You can't target specific areas of the body for weight loss. You need steady weight loss, and it'll come off your intended area at some point.

For workouts, if you aim at losing weight, the obvious choice is to burn it off by doing cardio. What you should do in the gym(or out of it) is up to you: Do you like running, cycling, rowing? Then target those machines.

As a vegan you should focus on your macros(proportion of protein,carbs and healthy fats). Vegan food can be carb heavy and lack protein(which saturates a bit - and is therefore good for weight loss). You need to learn which vegan foods are good in protein(green beans for example) and ramp it up there.